# Cassandra LOCAL_QUORUM is waiting for remote datacenter responses

Tags: cassandra, replication, database-replication, consistency, eventual-consistency

We have a 2 datacenters ( One in EU and one in US ) cluster with 4 nodes each deployed in AWS. 
The nodes are separated in 3 racks ( Availability zones ) each.
In the cluster we have a keyspace test with replication: NetworkTopologyStrategy, eu-west:3, us-east:3
In the keyspace we have a table called mytable that has only one row 'id' text

Now, we were doing some tests on the performance of the database.
In CQLSH with a consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM we were doing some inserts with TRACING ON and we noticed that the requests were not working as we expected them.

From the tracing data we found out that the coordinator node was hitting as expected 2 other local nodes and was also sending a request to one of the remote datacenter nodes. Now the problem here was that the coordinator was waiting not only for the local nodes ( who finished in no time ) but for the remote nodes too.

Now since our 2 datacenters are geographically far away from each other, our requests were taking a very long time to complete.

Notes:
- This does not happen with DSE but our understanding was we don't need to pay crazy money for LOCAL_QUORUM to work as is expected

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability that you're hitting [CASSANDRA-9753](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9753) when the non-zero `dclocal_read_repair_chance` will trigger a query against remote DC. You need to check the trace for hint about triggering of read repair for your query. If you really get it, then you can set `dclocal_read_repair_chance` to 0 - this parameter is deprecated anyway...

Answer (score 1):

For functional and performance tests it would be better to use the driver instead of CQLSH, as most of the time that will be the way that you are interacting with the database.

For this case, you may use a DC-aware policy like

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
            DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
                    .withLocalDc("myLocalDC")
                    .build()
    ).build();
```

This is modified from the example [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/), where all the clauses that allow to interact with remote datacenters are removed, as your purpose is to isolate the calls to local.

Comment: Cassandra driver should have the DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy set by default and it should be token aware. And the way our distribution is set up i know i am hitting the correct region from the driver